# Parse txt to blocks

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

i have a txt file, which has the following structure

```
start
id=1
date=21.05.2018
summ=500
end

start
id=7
date=23.05.2018
summ=500
owner=guest
end
```

and i need to parse it in a list of dictionaries (str : str (even it is int type or date: convert it to string)). i.e. split it on block with `start` `end`, and after that split it on `=` symbol. The amount of lines between `start` `end` can be different. D
But a can't realize it. I tried something like this:

```
d ={}
arr = []
ind = 0
for line in plines:
    ind = ind + 1
    if 'startpayment' in line:
        print('ind = ' + str(ind))
        for i in range(ind, len(plines)):
            print(i)
            key, value = plines[i].strip().split('=')
            if type(value) == 'str':
                d[key] = str(value)
            elif type(value) == 'int':
                 d[key] = int(value)
            arr.append(d)
            if 'endpayment' in line:
                break
```

Could someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your desired result structure is not quite clear--you should show the desired result from your given example txt file. For example, what formats do you want the dictionary values in? Are the values for the `id` and `summ` keys to be integers or strings? Is the value for the `date` key to be a string? If a record is missing a key, such as `owner` missing from the first record, is it just to be skipped? Also, is the format of the file guaranteed to be error-free? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited question. dictionary: "str" : "str".

Comment: Thanks for the edit and comment--they do answer my questions. However, if you want to continue asking questions here, you really should show the desired output from your example input, as explained in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your first question is pretty good, otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try something like this:

```
from itertools import takewhile

with open('data.txt') as in_file:
    items = [line.strip() for line in in_file.read().split()]
    # ['start', 'id=1', 'date=21.05.2018', 'summ=500', 'end', 'start', 'id=7', 'date=23.05.2018', 'summ=500', 'owner=guest']

    pos = [i for i, item in enumerate(items) if item == 'start']
    # [0, 5]

    blocks = [list(takewhile(lambda x: x != 'end', items[i+1:])) for i in pos]
    # [['id=1', 'date=21.05.2018', 'summ=500'], ['id=7', 'date=23.05.2018', 'summ=500', 'owner=guest']]

    print([dict(x.split('=') for x in block) for block in blocks])
```

Which Outputs:

```
[{'id': '1', 'date': '21.05.2018', 'summ': '500'}, {'id': '7', 'date': '23.05.2018', 'summ': '500', 'owner': 'guest'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Regex**.

```
import re

with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = re.findall("(?<=\\bstart\\b).*?(?=\\bend\\b)", data, flags=re.DOTALL)   #Find the required data from text

r = []
for i in data:
    val =  filter(None, i.split("\n"))
    d = {}
    for j in val:
        s = j.split("=")    #Split by "=" to form key-value pair
        d[s[0]] = s[1]
    r.append(d)             #Append to list
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'date': '21.05.2018', 'summ': '500', 'id': '1'}, {'date': '23.05.2018', 'owner': 'guest', 'summ': '500', 'id': '7'}]
```

Comment: Won't this fail if the string 'start' or 'end' is included in one of the keys or values? I.e. in your `findall` shouldn't you make sure that the 'start's and 'end's are alone on the line?

Comment: @RoryDaulton. Looking at the data in the OPs text the content is separated by `start-end` block. If the key value has the block names then OP should change the format of the text

Comment: I'm saying that, for example, the 'owner' in a record could possibly be "wit's-end". I believe that would cause any later key-value pairs in the record to be ignored. The change to your code to handle this would be pretty minimal--just change the `findall` string to `"^start$(.*?)^end$"`, I believe. I am no regular-expressions expert so I could be wrong, so my questions are actually questions.

Comment: oh Thank you sir. I understand now. I have now used `\b` to get exact match :)

Comment: Using `\b` doesn't address @RoryDaulton's example: `\bend\b` still matches "wit's-end".

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple parser with recursion that attempts to find data between `start` and `end` blocks:

```
import re
class Parser:
  def __init__(self, source:str):
    self.source = iter(filter(None, source.split('\n')))
    self.results = []
    self.parse()
  @staticmethod
  def to_dict(between_blocks):
    return dict(re.split('\s*\=\s*', i) for i in between_blocks)
  def parse(self):
    _line = next(self.source, None)
    if _line is not None:
      if _line == 'start':
        scope = []
        while True:
         _temp = next(self.source, None)
         if _temp is None:
           raise Exception("Missing 'end' tag")
         if _temp != 'end':
           scope.append(_temp)
         else:
           break
        self.results.append(Parser.to_dict(filter(None, scope)))
      self.parse()
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'{Parsed}({self.results})'

print(Parser(open('filename.txt').read())).results)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'date': '21.05.2018', 'summ': '500'}, {'id': '7', 'date': '23.05.2018', 'summ': '500', 'owner': 'guest'}]
```

---

Tests:

```
tests = [[
"""
start
id=1
date=21.05.2018
summ=500
""", Exception],
[
 """
 start
 name = someone
 age = 18
 id = 23
 end
 start
 name = someoneelse
 age = 45
 id = 55
 end
 start
 name = lastname
 age = 34
 id = 5
 end
""", None]
]
for text, is_error in tests:    
   try:
     _ = Parser(text)
   except:
     assert is_error == Exception
   else:
     assert is_error is None

print('all tests passed')
```

Output:

```
all tests passed
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest algorithm I could think of, if I get your question right.

```
d ={}
arr = []

for line in plines:
  if line == 'start':
    continue
  elif line =='end':
    arr.append(d)
    continue
  else:
    list_key_value = line.split('=')    
    d[list_key_value[0]] = int(list_key_value[1]) if 
    type(list_key_value[1]) == 'int' else str(list_key_value[1])
print (arr)
```

Output:
    `[{'id': '7', 'date': '23.05.2018', 'summ': '500', 'owner': 'guest'}, 
     {'id': '7', 'date': '23.05.2018', 'summ': '500', 'owner': 'guest'}]`

Comment: thank u, but somewhere there is an error, cause output has the same data.

Comment: After `arr.append(d)`, you need `d = {}`.

Comment: Also, `line.split('=')` always returns a list of strings, so `type(list_key_value[1]) == 'int'` will never be true (and anyway, the OP asked for a `str:str` dictionary). Moreover, the `str` is unnecessary in `str(list_key_value[1])`. So you could just say `d[list_key_value[0]] = list_key_value[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the text file, provided you keep some context: start a new dictionnary on each *start* line and add it to the list on each *end* line.

Code could be:

```
def parse(fd):
    """Parse a file, fd is expected to be a file object"""
    resul = []     # the list of dictionaries to return
    d = None       # an individual dict initialized to None
    linenum = 0
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        linenum += 1
        if line.startswith('end'):
            if d is not None:
                resul.append(d)
                d = None
        elif line.startswith('start'):
            d = {}
        elif len(line) != 0:
            key, val = line.split('=', 1)
            d[key] = val
    return resul
```

Syntax errors in the file (missing start or end lines, other incorrect lines) are not handled here:

- a missing end line will cause the previous key=val lines to be discarded
- a missing start line will cause an exception because *None is not subscriptable* on next key=val line
- an other incorrect line (no `=` sign) should cause an exception *ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)*